# can iuse django-scrapy app in production

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I have so many tasks to be done via scrapy on prodcution server.
As my manager wants to add or remove the urls to scrap and he wants the web interface.

I am thinking of making the web app for that

I have found this link
https://github.com/holgerd77/django-dynamic-scraper/

I just want to know that can I use that in production or I can manually call scrapy in my django app and I don't need to use that app.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried that and looks alright to me. They also have good [documentaion](http://django-dynamic-scraper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) written there

They are good if you are new and want to get things going. but i think once you get used to the scrapy and django in detail you almost don't need it

Answer (score 0):

Python modules, including scrapy, are most of the time plug-and-play so yes, you should be able to do it with scrapy itself. And you will probably benefit from clearer documentation.